# How do I set up my API to require an API key with amazon API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have been following advice on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061041/using-an-api-key-in-amazon-api-gateway) I've created an API key on AWS and set my POST method to require an API key.

I have also setup a usage plan and linked that API key to it.

My API key is enabled

When I have been testing requests with postman, my request still goes through without any additional headers.

I was expecting no requests to go through unless I had included a header in my request like this `"x-api-key":"my_api_key"`

Do I need to change the endpoint I send requests to in postman for them to go through API Gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to enable API key for each method then needs to be enabled API key required true for each method.

Go to resources--> select your resource and method, go to Method Request and set "API Key Required" to true.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-key-source.html

Comment: You make some good points, I don't find AWS docs very friendly, but I had already done that, I had to deploy my endpoint and use the `"invoke url"` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want, I've made the following script to enable the API key on every method for certain API. It requires the [jq tool for advanced JSON parsing](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

You can find the [script to enable the API key for all methods of an API Gateway API on this gist](https://gist.github.com/lmiguelmh/a9928c94e4c424b1fef8a52a370a89f8#file-enable_api_gateway_api_key_for_methods-sh).

```
#!/bin/bash

api_gateway_method_enable_api_key() {
  local api_id=$1
  local method_id=$2
  local method=$3
  aws --profile "$profile" --region "$region" \
    apigateway update-method \
    --rest-api-id "$api_id" \
    --resource-id "$method_id" \
    --http-method "$method" \
    --patch-operations op="replace",path="/apiKeyRequired",value="true"
}

# change this to 1 in order to execute the update
do_update=0

profile=your_profile
region=us-east-1
id=your_api_id
tmp_file="/tmp/list_of_endpoint_and_methods.json"

aws --profile $profile --region $region \
  apigateway get-resources \
  --rest-api-id $id \
  --query 'items[?resourceMethods].{p:path,id:id,m:resourceMethods}' >"$tmp_file"

while read -r line; do
  path=$(jq -r '.p' <<<"$line")
  method_id=$(jq -r '.id' <<<"$line")
  echo "$path"

  # do not update OPTIONS method
  for method in GET POST PUT DELETE; do
    has_method=$(jq -r ".m.$method" <<<"$line")
    if [ "$has_method" != "null" ]; then
      if [ $do_update -eq 1 ]; then
        api_gateway_method_enable_api_key "$id" "$method_id" "$method"
        echo "  $method method changed"
      else
        echo "  $method method will be changed"
      fi
    fi
  done

done <<<"$(jq -c '.[]' "$tmp_file")"
```