# AWS API Gateway - "Require API key" on everything

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway

Currently, this is how I am securing API gateway endpoints.

I set an API key and a usage plan and then **for each** endpoint:

```
"Endpoint > Method Request > API Key Required = true"
```

I would like to secure everything in the API this way.
Is there a more convenient way to do it?
Everything means all endpoints and all methods.

Answer (score 0):

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html), API Keys are managed on a per method basis, and therefore cannot be applied at the resource or global API level.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70296022/2692914 I've put a script for the part that enables the API key for all methods of certain API.

Also, you can find the [script to enable the API key for all methods of an API Gateway API on this gist](https://gist.github.com/lmiguelmh/a9928c94e4c424b1fef8a52a370a89f8#file-enable_api_gateway_api_key_for_methods-sh).