# How to get api gateway key name in aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I create the api in `"Api-gateway"` and set `"API Key Required"` to true in Method execution settings , But in lambda function i only get the `"apiKeyId"` from the request header. Is there any way to get the `apiKeyName` too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061041/using-an-api-key-in-amazon-api-gateway -- this might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the ApiKey name is not available within the executing lambda. You can only use the SDK to query all keys and then filter manually with code.

On a side note, you can also do this in a custom authorizer and map the name to the invocation context. This way you only have to code it once and all lambdas get the parameter as a context variable. Another bonus of this implementation is, that the result of custom authorizer is cached.

[nodejs implementation of custom authorizer with apikey name mapper](https://gist.github.com/JensWalter/0c24acb9bcf6574feecbcfa04d6a5fcf)

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer above I found I could get this to work with the following code:

```
const APIGateway = require("aws-sdk").APIGateway;
    
const apiKeyId = event.requestContext.identity.apiKeyId;
const apiKeyDetails = await new APIGateway().getApiKey({apiKey:apiKeyId}).promise();
const apiKeyName = apiKeyDetails.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think you can use this `apiGatway API referance` or use the `aws CLI` to get the name of the key
  [Amazon API Gateway REST API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/apikey-by-key/)
  or
  [AWS CLI command referance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-api-key.html)

Comment: Is there any way to make apiKeyName available in request header in lamda function?.
e.g in event.requestContext.identity i got the value information.

`"identity": {
 "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
 "cognitoIdentityId": null,
 "apiKey": "iqUQOowmC7",
  "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
 "userArn": null,
 "apiKeyId": "r3k",
 "userAgent": "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0",
}`

i need apiKeyName too.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but here is a way to get the details for the API key, as others have said its necessary to fetch them.

```
import { APIGateway } from 'aws-sdk'
// Add the below to your handler
const apiKey = event.requestContext.identity.apiKey 
const apiKeyDetails = await new APIGateway().getApiKey({ apiKey }).promise()
```

Now its possible to fetch the api key name, tags, description etc.

Comment: I had to tweak this slightly to get it to work as getApiKey expects an apiKeyId:

const APIGateway = require("aws-sdk").APIGateway;

const apiKeyId = event.requestContext.identity.apiKeyId`;

const apiKeyDetails = await new APIGateway().getApiKey({apiKey:apiKeyId}).promise();

Comment: Likely due to you having an updated version of pulumi since this was posted

Answer (score 0):

with AWSSDK.APIGateway for .Net:

By name (to check if already exists)

```
var apiGatewayClient = new AmazonAPIGatewayClient();
var getMethodRequest = new GetApiKeysRequest() { NameQuery = "SomeApiKeyName" };
var getMethodResponse = await apiGatewayClient.GetApiKeysAsync(getMethodRequest);
return getMethodResponse.Items != null && getMethodResponse.Items.Any() && getMethodResponse.Items[0].Name == "SomeName";
```

What you are referring as `"apiKeyId"` is indeed the `"api key"` which comes in the `"x-api-key"` header, because an apy key has another (internal) id. Said this, you can also find the api name by `Usage Plan Id` with method `GetUsagePlanKeysAsync`:

```
var p = new GetUsagePlanKeysRequest() { UsagePlanId = usagePlanId };
var result = await apiGatewayClient.GetUsagePlanKeysAsync(p);
return result.Items.Where(c => c.Value == apiKey).Select(s => s.Name);
```

If you don't have a `Usage Plan Id` you can obtain the complete list with method GetUsagePlansAsync:

```
var result = await apiGatewayClient.GetUsagePlansAsync(new GetUsagePlansRequest()));
return result.Items;
```

Or if you know the `api key Id` and `Usage Plan Id`, you can find the api key name with method `GetUsagePlanKeyAsync`:

```
var p = new GetUsagePlanKeyRequest() { UsagePlanId = usagePlanId, KeyId = apiKeyId };
var result = await apiGatewayClient.GetUsagePlanKeyAsync(p));
return result.Name;
```